# Attach a file to rich text item in Lotus Document

Tags: lotus-notes, attachment, lotusscript, lotus, richtext

I'm trying to attach a file to my document in Lotus.My file is situated here in c:\dev\3.txt, my form is Test and the richtext field where i want to attach the field is "test". I tried this Lotusscript code to attach the file to the field 'test' but it put the file in the end of the document and not in the field:

```
Dim uidoc As notesuidocument
Dim w As New notesuiworkspace
Dim object As NotesEmbeddedObject
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
Set uidoc=w.currentdocument
Set doc = uidoc.Document

Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem( "test" )
Set object= rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", "C:\dev\3.txt")
doc.Form = "Test"

Call doc.Save( True, False)

Call uidoc.Close
```

Comment: Is "Test" really a Richtextitem? i can't see anything wrong in your code at the first glance...

Comment: It looks like this is action button code, so there may be an issue with front-end/back-end doc synchronization.  It's been too long since I played with it, but if that's what's happening then this old technique might be the key: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/dd507a5be7cc2e4285256eec005f56ef?OpenDocument

Comment: Follow-up on Torsten's question: you may want to check on this using
 If (rtitem.Type=RICHTEXT) Then ... Or maybe even
 If (doc.HasItem("test")) Then ...

Answer (score 2):

try to use this code:

```
files = workspace.OpenFileDialog(True, "File List","", "")
Forall i In files
  Set object = rtitem.EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "",i,"")
End Forall
```